# How do I change the source for autcomplete with a dynamic variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I hope you can follow me in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DLLVw/482/).

I'm trying to send an extra variable  to my source in jquery autocomplete. This can usually be achieved by just adding the variable after your sourche URL like so: `source:'myURL.php?supplier=myvariable'` .

The var I'm trying to send however is dynamic, it's a variable that is either true or false depending on a checkbox that is checked or not. Like so:

```
var dynamicVar = $('#y').prop('checked');

$('#y').change(function(){
    dynamicVar = $('#y').prop('checked');
    console.log(dynamicVar);
});
```

Now I tried to use this variable in my source for autocomplete like so:

```
source:'myURL.php?supplier='+dynamicVar
```

As you can see in [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DLLVw/482/) (if you look for the GET URL in console), this variable is always false, whether the checkbox is checked or not.

How do I edit my code so that the requested URL in my demo is`http://fiddle.jshell.net/DLLVw/482/show/myURL.php?supplier=false&term=whatItyped` when the checkbox is unchecked, and `http://fiddle.jshell.net/DLLVw/482/show/myURL.php?supplier=true&term=whatItyped` when the checkbox is checked?

P.S. type in the input field to see the GET url

UPDATE: artm's code returns the correct content, however this breaks the autocomplete functionality on the input.

ORIGINAL NON-Dummy code:

jQuery:

```
var dynamicVar = $('#zxc').prop('checked');

$('#zxc').change(function(){
    dynamicVar = $('#zxc').prop('checked');
    dynamicVar = $('#zxc').is(':checked');
    console.log(dynamicVar);
});

function getChecked(){
    return $('#zxc').is(':checked');
}
$('#q').autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
          url: "getklanten.php",
          data: {
            term : request.term,
            supplier : $('#zxc').is(':checked')
          }
        });
    }
})  .data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
    return $( "<li>" )
    .append( "<a>" + item.naam + "</a>" )
    .appendTo( ul );
};
```

Response in console:

```
 [{"naam":"Company name","id":12345}]
```

Comment: What is this dynamicVar variable. Do you use it somewhere els also? If not just try `source:'myURL.php?supplier='+$('#y').prop('checked');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://jsfiddle.net/DLLVw/483/

When you pass dynamicVar to the autocomplete, it uses the value of dynamicVar at the time when you called autoComplete. So it's always false, ragardless of the state, since dynamicVar doesn't change when you change the check box. If you want to pass dynamic values you need to use:

```
$('#x').autocomplete({
    //source:'myURL.php?supplier='+dynamicVar
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
         url: "myURL.php",
         data: {
            term : request.term,
            supplier : $('#y').is(':checked')
          }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: This gives the correct call to the PHP file, it also returns the data as intended, but for some reason it breaks the autocomplete list. Unfortunately I can not re-create this in the fiddle since I can not call to an actual PHP script that returns data from JSFIDDLE.

Comment: @user3008011 Does it all work when you use your original `source`? And it only breaks when you use the code here? If that's the case either switch them around, i.e. data: {            supplier : $('#y').is(':checked'),
            term : request.term

          }` or otherwise it sounds like a new question.

Comment: I'm not able to get the autocomplete functionality with your supplied code. Which is weird since it does return the correct data in console. 
My actual code is a little more complex than the dummy code, so I included it in the original question.

Comment: Was too late for an edit -.-. When I replace the ajax function for my original url it all does work as intended, without offcourse the missing variable.